# extracting particular text from link using gsub in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gsub

I have a link by this text,

**s= "http://xyz.com/Getid.ashx?JobID=250920&JobTitle=office+junior&seswitch=1&lid=801&AVSDM=2012-11-22+11%3a33%3a00"**

I need to extract two information from this link

1)JobID which "250920"

2)JobTitle which is "office junior"

Is this possible by using gsub will I be able to get only those text from the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `.match` with a regex:

`result = s.match(/JobID\=(\d+).+JobTitle\=([a-zA-Z+0-9]+)\&/)`

`result[1] #JobID`

`result[2] #JobTile`

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect can you suggest some online resources to learn about the regular expressions in ruby or rails